# How to set sass with compass and coffeescript in meanio

Tags: coffeescript, compass-sass, mean-stack

I find mean.io (MongoDB Espress Angular Node) very interesting.

I'm used to work with coffeescript, sass and compass.
I would like to start a project with all these and not with pure js and css as the default setup does.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible but right now there is a bit of overhead required to get setup.

Have a look at https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee for info about converting coffescript to js using grunt. mean.io uses a lot of the grunt tools.

I would also recommend emailing a colleage of mine lior@linnovate.net. He has recently been building a sass package using the mean package system.

To see currently available packages have a look at http://www.mean.io/#!/packages